# display array elements in block list / table

Tags: php, html

I have an array of counting numbers. I want to display them in a table or block list with specific number of columns, say 6 using php's `foreach` and `echo` function, so that i can make it in a loop. How can I make this possible using `css` or `html`??

Here is what I am talking about

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  13 |  14 |  15 |  16 |  17 |  18 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  19 |  20 |  21 |  22 |  23 |  24 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

It will be better if done by setting `<table>`

Comment: So what kind of solution are you looking for now? PHP and a table or a list and CSS?

Comment: Yes, a `<table>` is the right choice here. Have you tried writing any code yet?

Comment: hi @Gumbo, I have a `<table>` and `</table>`.. I want to fill inside, i mean, i want to print / echo `<tr>` and `<td>` with php. I dont know how to do this... :(

Comment: So the question isn't really anything to do with CSS? Just how to use php to generate a `table` with the given constraints?

Comment: @Matt Ball, I tried a table and then made echos in condition that the number having remainder 1 by dividing with6 will have an extra `<tr>` in front, but was not able to find 100% success... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $elements = array_chunk($elements, 6);
 $html = '<table>';
 foreach($elements as $tr){
     $html .= '<tr>';
     foreach($tr as $td) $html .= '<td>'.$td.'</td>';
     $html .= '</tr>';
 }
 $html .= '</table>;
```

Comment: echo would be after the last line here
`echo $table;`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php
        $columns = 6;
        $i = 0;
        foreach($array as $item)
        {
            echo "<td>$item<td>";
            if($i++ >= $columns)
            {
                $i = 0;
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
     </tr>
</table>
```